# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax SQL MOCK SBA assignment

Tags: mariadb

Query failed to run properly in MariaDB SQL using sequel pro. I've tried a couple of times but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Error messages:

> [ERROR in query 1] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(30),
> LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
> CITY VARCHAR2(60)
> )' at line 3
> [ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(100),
> CITY VARCHAR2(60),
> SALES_TAX_RATE NUMBER(6,5)
> )' at line 3
> [ERROR in query 3] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(30),
> PRICE NUMBER(5,2)
> )' at line 3

Code that I am trying to run on my computer:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
    USER_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    CITY VARCHAR2(60)
);

CREATE TABLE STORES (
    STORE_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR2(100),
    CITY VARCHAR2(60),
    SALES_TAX_RATE NUMBER(6,5)
);

CREATE TABLE ITEMS (
    ITEM_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    PRICE NUMBER(5,2)
);

CREATE TABLE ORDERS (
    ORDER_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    USER_ID INT,
    STORE_ID INT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserID FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_StoreID FOREIGN KEY (STORE_ID) REFERENCES STORES(STORE_ID)
);
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: What version of MariaDB? You seem to be having some confusion over what you have (the Q was tagged MySQL and SQLS also) - anyhoos, I suspect whatever DB you're running doesn't have VARCHAR2; use VARCHAR. VARCHAR2 is an Oracle/Enterprise Maria thing

Comment: This, like many questions, is far easier answered from the [official docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/varchar/)

Comment: version 10.5 of mariadb

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. For my version of mariadb 10.5. All VARCHAR2 needs to be replaced with VARCHAR and NUMBER with DECIMAL and then all the tables will be created.